# Adding negative zero floats results in 1.0f only when using custom Vector class

Tags: java, vector, floating-point, processing

When I calculate the dot product of two vectors `a = (-0, -0, -5)` and `b = (0, 1, 0)` using my custom `Vector` class, it gives me `1` when it should've given `0`. However, when I use `PVector`, it works as expected. I took a look at the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/processing/source/browse/trunk/processing/core/src/processing/core/PVector.java) for `PVector`, but I noticed nothing that was different for what I was trying to do.

I suspect this has something to do with how `-0.0f` is equal to `+1.0f` and I know I could just use `PVector`, but it's strange that my implementation is broken. Does anyone know why it's broken? (I'm using Processing 1.5.1)

Simple test case comparing dot products for `PVector` and my `Vector`:

```
void setup() {
  Vector a = new Vector(-0, -0, -5);
  Vector b = new Vector(0, 1, 0);
  println(a.dotProduct(b));

  PVector pA = new PVector(-0, -0, -5);
  PVector pB = new PVector(0, 1, 0);
  println(pA.dot(pB));
}

class Vector {
  public float x, y, z, w;

  Vector(float x, float y, float z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.w = 1;
  }

  void doScale(float scalar) {
    this.x *= scalar;
    this.y *= scalar;
    this.z *= scalar;
  }

  float dotProduct(Vector other) {
    return this.x * other.x + this.y + other.y + this.z * other.z; 
  }

}
```

Comment: Please tag with language (Java). And *why would* -0f be equal to 1f? That just sounds like nonsense :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
float dotProduct(Vector other) {
  return this.x * other.x + this.y + other.y + this.z * other.z; 
}
```

You're *adding* `this.y` and `other.y` together, instead of multiplying them. It should be:

```
float dotProduct(Vector other) {
  return this.x * other.x + this.y * other.y + this.z * other.z; 
}
```

Personally I'd add brackets for readability:

```
float dotProduct(Vector other) {
  return (this.x * other.x) + (this.y * other.y) + (this.z * other.z);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typo: should be `this.y * other.y` perhaps?